# Forks and parent child communication

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork, ipc

I am new to Linux System Commands, and IPC related topics.

I have a child who calculates a given number's factorial, and then passes the result back to the parent. The parent will then print the received output.

I must do this ***WITHOUT*** using any kind of  ***PIPES***. 
At this point I have done a small amount of research on different types of IPC.The two routes I was considering was File Mapping and Mail Slot.
However considering how basic the task is, they all seem too complicated.

What are some simple ways that I could solve this problem?

Comment: The simple way to solve this problem is with a pipe.  If there is an artificial constraint against using the standard solution, remove the constraint.  If you really want to do it without using a pipe, look at shared memory and/or a socket.

Comment: This is for a class, the class requirements state to not use a pipe for this assignment. Thanks for the advice, will look into that!

Comment: The usual answer to questions like this is "whatever you were taught in class", but we don't know what you were taught in class. If it were up to me and I wanted some fun, I'd use semaphores, one for each possible bit of the answer.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thus far I have learned merely the concepts of each variation and why it's useful. What I'm looking for is something that is simple to implement. I'll look into semaphores!

Comment: There's memory mapping, posix shared memory, semaphores, unix sockets, IP sockets, even reading and writing to the same file. Read the documentation for them and decide what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is forking the children, create a shared location in the parent, and then have the child fill in the result in that space, since all memory is accessible by the parent and child at the time of doing the `fork()`.